# Woocommerce minimum order by category/quantity

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, cart

I'm wondering if it would be possible to create an if statement where if a customer hasn't added enough (quantity - not price) of a specific product category to their order, a message shows up saying they need to add more to avoid a surcharge. I'm thinking something along the lines of the minimum order amount snippet [documented here](http://docs.woothemes.com/document/minimum-order-amount/):

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_checkout_process', 'wc_minimum_order_amount' );
    function wc_minimum_order_amount() {
        global $woocommerce;
        $minimum = 50;
    if ( $woocommerce->cart->total() < $minimum ) {
        $woocommerce->add_error( sprintf( 'You must have an order with a minimum of %s to place your order.' , $minimum ) );
    }
}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You seem to have the answer already there in the code, so what is the question?

Comment: The above code calculates the entire cart total based on the monetary value - what I am after is a minimum quantity of products from a particular category regardless of price.

Answer (score 2):

This might be done by using the `woocommerce_checkout_process` and `woocommerce_before_cart` [Woocommerce Hooks](https://docs.woocommerce.com/wc-apidocs/hook-docs.html).

So add this code at your theme's [`functions.php` file](https://codex.wordpress.org/Functions_File_Explained)  (change the *Name Your category* string):

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_checkout_process', 'wc_minimum_order_amount' );
add_action( 'woocommerce_before_cart' , 'wc_minimum_order_amount' );

function wc_minimum_order_amount() {

    $minimum = 50; //Qty product

    if ( WC()->cart->cart_contents_count < $minimum ) {

        $draught_links = array();

        foreach(WC()->cart->get_cart() as $cart_item_key => $values ) {

            $_product = $values['data'];

            $terms = get_the_terms( $_product->id, 'product_cat' );

            foreach ($terms as $term) {
                $draught_links[] = $term->name;
            }   

        }

        if (in_array("Name Your category", $draught_links)){
            $on_draught = true;
        }else{
            $on_draught = false;
        }

        if( is_cart() ) {

            if($on_draught){

                wc_print_notice( 
                    sprintf( 'You must have an order with a minimum of %s to place your order, your current order total is %s.' , 
                         $minimum , 
                         WC()->cart->cart_contents_count
                    ), 'error' 
                );

            }

        } else {

            if($on_draught){

                wc_add_notice( 
                    sprintf( 'You must have an order with a minimum of %s to place your order, your current order total is %s.' , 
                        $minimum , 
                        WC()->cart->cart_contents_count
                    ), 'error' 
                );

            }

        }
    }

}
```

Comment: please provide more information about your answer and describe your code for next users...

Answer (score 0):

From the [WooCommerce Docs](http://docs.woothemes.com/wc-apidocs/class-WC_Cart.html)

> public float $cart_contents_count - The total count of the cart items.

So it stands to reason that this should do what you need:

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_checkout_process', 'wc_minimum_order_amount' );
function wc_minimum_order_amount() {
    global $woocommerce;
    $minimum = 50;
    if ( $woocommerce->cart->cart_contents_count < $minimum ) {
        $woocommerce->add_error( sprintf( 'You must have an order with a minimum of %s to place your order.' , $minimum ) );
    }
}
```

Comment: That's on the way, but I need to limit it to the count of products in a specific category.